# List items with separation but without margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cover the top of my site with list items.

My list items are appearing like this:

[image]

And i don't know why this separation between them. They don't have any margin and padding.

Anyone knows why is this?

HTML:

```
        <ul class="listras-lista">
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
            <li class="listras-lista_item"></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.listras-lista {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.listras-lista_item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #CC00CC;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's whitespace that causes the spaces. If you can, change the markup so that `</li><li>` are together

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `display: inline-block;`. Change it to `float:left;`.